Error uninstalling MySQL Shell, Config.Msi/b1a0340.rbf
I'm trying to uninstall MySQL Shell 8.0 from my Windows 2019 Server but I get the following error when I attempt to uninstall / update the program:
1: Error writing to file: C:\Config.Msi\b1a0340.rbf.   Verify that you have access to that directory.

I'm running the installer as an Administrator, and there doesn't seem to be a C:\Config.Msi folder at all
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
